# 2 level atomic system interacting with Black body radiation. Relaxation time issue

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, laser, blackbody

I am studying the transient regime of a 2 level atomic system ($N_1,N_2$) interacting with a blackbody radiation from a source at constant temperature $T_{nr}$. 
The initial state of the atomic system is temperature $T_a=0$ with all the $N_0$ atoms in the ground state.

The atomic system will receive energy from the source by stimulated absorption and release energy through spontaneous emission and stimulated emission. The rate equation is then :

\begin{align*} 
\frac{dN_{1}}{dt}=-\frac{dN_{2}}{dt}=-W_{12}N_{1}+W_{21}N_{2}+\gamma_{rad}N_{2} 
\end{align*}

where :
\begin{align*} 
W_{12}=W_{21}=W_{bbr}=\frac{\gamma_{rad}}{\exp\left[\hbar\omega_a/kT_{rad}\right]-1}
\end{align*}

This rate equation turns out to be a first order equation whose solution for $N_1$ is then :
\begin{align*} 
N_{1}=N_{eq1}+(N_{0}-N_{eq1})e^{-t/\tau}
\end{align*}

where :
\begin{align*} 
N_{eq1}=N_{0}.\frac{1}{1+\exp\left[-\hbar\omega_a/kT_{rad}\right]}
\end{align*} 
and 
\begin{align*} 
 \tau=\frac{1}{\gamma_{rad}}\left(\frac{\exp\left[\hbar\omega_a/kT_{rad}\right]-1}{\exp\left[\hbar\omega_a/kT_{rad}\right]+1}\right) 
\end{align*}

The behavior of $N_{1eq}$ seems fine since it always remains higher than $N_{2eq}$. For infinite $T_{rad}$ its value its asymptotic value is $N_0/2$.
If we look at the equilibrium temperature of the atomic system it is also consistent since it ends being equal to $T_{rad}$ whatever the value of $T_{rad}$ is.

The problem I see is that the behavior of the relaxation time decreases when increasing $T_{rad}$ to reach 0 as the temperature $T_{rad}$ goes to infinity.
There should be a mistake somewhere.

Comment: is $\hbar \omega$ the difference between the energy levels $N_2$ and $N_1$?

Comment: yes it corresponds to the energy difference between the 2 levels as the atoms follow Boltzmann statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes perfect sense that for $T_{rad}\rightarrow \infty$, the system will instantaneously equilibrate into a state in which the highest possible occupation number of the higher energy state $N_2 = \frac{N_0}{2}$, is achieved.

Comment: As you say it actually, the probability of a stimulated transition is infinite as Trad is infinite which makes this instantaneous changing state consistent! Though the behavior of the relaxation time being $\tau = 1/\gamma_{rad} $ is a bit weird when Trad = 0 as there is already equilibrium